# Why does my page number reset to 1 after the table of contents, and how can I avoid this?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

For the table of contents, I change the page number in the footer from roman numerals to arabic numerals. But the problem is that the page number will be reset to 1 after the table of contents. I want to make it continue following the page number of table of contents. Could anyone tell me how to do that?

The following is my code for setup header-footer and chapter page:

```
% Setup fancy headings
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
  \newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{#1}{}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\thesection\ #1}%
}

\fancyhead[LE]{\fancyplain{}{\includegraphics[height=0.56in, width=1.5in]{logo.jpg}}}
\fancyhead[CE]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\fancyplain{}{\includegraphics[height=0.56in, width=1.5in]{logo.jpg}}}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\ page \arabic{page}\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\fancyfoot[CE]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\ page \arabic{page}\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}  

%---------- Set up chapter style -------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 2pt \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \thispagestyle {fancyplain}
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ 
    {\raggedleft \reset@font% 
     \fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{22pt}{12}\selectfont%
     \bfseries\thechapter\nobreak\hspace{1ex}}%
    {\raggedright \reset@font%
      \fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{22pt}{12}\selectfont%
      \bfseries #1}%
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \par\nobreak
    \textcolor{orange}{\thickhrulefill}
    \vspace{26pt}
    \par\nobreak

  }}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \thispagestyle {fancyplain}
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ 
    {\raggedright \reset@font%
      \fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{22pt}{12}\selectfont%
      \bfseries #1}%
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \par\nobreak
    \textcolor{orange}{\thickhrulefill}
    \vspace{26pt}
    \par\nobreak

  }}

\makeatother
```

Answer (score 5):

Switching to a different `\pagenumbering` will reset the `page` counter. Use an auxiliary counter to save the value of `page` after the ToC, and reset the `page` counter to this value after switching to `arabic`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\newcounter{mypageno}
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \oldtableofcontents
  \cleardoublepage
  \setcounter{mypageno}{\value{page}}%
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \setcounter{page}{\value{mypageno}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

(The [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext/) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

EDIT: MWE changed -- `\tableofcontents` is redefined in the preamble (this could be used in a `.sty` file). Note that I'm assuming there should be a page break after the ToC.

Comment: Actually, my code is in .sty file. I want to adjust the .sty file in order to modify the .tex file. In this case, how can I do that? Thanks a lot.