# Ordered page numbering between arabic and roman numerals

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing a report and I would have the introduction, contents pages (everything before chapter 1) to be numbered in roman numerals, the main body to be arabic numerals, and then the appendices and bibliography to also be numbered in roman numerals. The first few pages is what I want, but if I use the command `\pagenumbering{arabic}` at the start of my first chapter, it starts numbering again at 1, whereas it should really start at 5. In addition, I then use the command `\pagenumbering{roman}` at the beginning of the appendices, and it again starts at I, instead of LXV (65). Is there any way to change this?

Thanks J.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an additional counter

```
\newcounter{mypageno}    
\setcounter{mypageno}{\value{page}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{\value{mypageno}}
```

see more explanation here:
[Why does my page number reset to 1 after the table of contents, and how can I avoid this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23620/why-does-my-page-number-reset-to-1-after-the-table-of-contents-and-how-can-i-av)

Comment: by "mypageno", is that a command, or do you mean for me to type the number I want it to be?

Comment: this is your own counter, so it's a variable. sorry, I forgot that one has to initialize this counter first with `\newcounter{...}`. I edited my answer. please also refer to the linked question below the sourcecode example

Comment: Excellent, this worked perfectly!